# Getting information from elements inside a CardLayout

Tags: java, jpanel, cardlayout

I am working with different panels which are part of a CardLayOut and every panel has some text fields, dropdown and checkbox elements inside, what I want to do is to get the information from every element using a button outside the layout.
I've found out how to get each element's properties, here is my definition of Cardlayout:

```
    layCard= new CardLayout();
    MainPanel.setLayout(layCard);
    MainPanel.add("Panel1",InfoPanel);
    MainPanel.add("Panel2",selection);
    MainPanel.add("Panel3",questions);
    MainPanel.add("Panel4",summary);
```

And here is my method when trying to get the information of an element inside a panel inside the MainPanel Inside the CardLayout:

```
private void printValues(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     


    System.out.println(""+MainPanel.getComponent(0).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(2).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleText());

}
```

In this case I'm accessing to the element 0 of the MainPanel which is InfoPanel and try to get value from the Child 2 which is a JtextField but I can' figure out how to get the value inside the field, I don't even know if there's a method that can help with this.
Do you have any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: If `MainPanel.getComponent(0).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(2).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleText()` gives you the `JTextField`, why don't you simply cast it to `JTextField` and then us the `JTextField#getText()` method?

Comment: There should be something like a getValue() Method. This method should return an "Object"-object, grab that object and cast it to String

Comment: Yes, the thing is that I have JTextFields and other components that doesn't return Strings as values, I tried casting the whole component as @STaefi said and it looks like it is working as I expected. Thanks to booth of you.

Comment: The whole thing is not a good idea, unless you have a very dynamic system of creating and adding components to random panels. If this is not the case, change your attitude and determine that in which panel user inputs are. Then use the direct reference of all component.

Comment: If you want to stick with the current code, you should place some `instanceof` conditions in your code for determining the type of every dummy component. Then you can cast to its real type and use the appropriate method to get the value for example: `JComboBox#getSelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Components` to an `Array` or `List` and simply call them from the relative index (`array[index]` or `list.get(index)`).

If you don't have direct access to the number required for the index, you can simply loop through the `Array` or `List` using a `for` loop.

That way you know what object types the `Components` are and you can either cast safely or directly access the right methods (`getText()`, etc).

Comment: Thanks, this can be a solution, I tried it and works, the thing is that I have already a lot of code and it will be harder to implement this solution for each panel.